# Using Properties in JMeter Random Timer

Tags: timer, jmeter

I'm trying to figure out how I can use properties to set delays before a request is set in Jmeter. I had my suite setup with Uniform Random Timer's and hard-coded values in the "Random Delay Maximum" and "Constant Delay Offset" fields, which worked great. For example:

```
<UniformRandomTimer guiclass="UniformRandomTimerGui" testclass="UniformRandomTimer" testname="Uniform Random Timer" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="RandomTimer.range">9879</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">3456</stringProp>
      </UniformRandomTimer>
```

But now I've replaced those hard-coded values with properties like this:

```
<UniformRandomTimer guiclass="UniformRandomTimerGui" testclass="UniformRandomTimer" testname="Uniform Random Timer" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="RandomTimer.range">${__P(GetRandomIntakeOffset)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">${__P(GetRandomIntakeRange)}</stringProp>
      </UniformRandomTimer>
```

I've verified the property is set by printing it in the console. I have also verified it is an integer and not a string property. However, the timer no longer works. There is no longer a delay before the request.

Has anyone got this working and have suggestions? Or alternative ways to get the same result.

Thank-you,

Gerry

Comment: if you get Debug Sampler and set it to report on properties ("JMeter propeerties:" set to True), do you see `GetRandomIntakeOffset` and `GetRandomIntakeRange`? Use View Results Tree for example to check

Comment: First of all - great idea. I was not aware of this debugSampler and it will prove useful. Thank-you. Secondly, yes, the properties GetRandomIntakeOffset and GetRandomIntakeRange are defined.

Comment: I tried, it works actually. One thing I noticed in your script is that you are setting `RandomTimer.range` is set to `${__P(GetRandomIntakeOffset)}` and the offset to `${__P(GetRandomIntakeRange)}`, while their names suggest opposite. Could it be that you just dont have a long enough `GetRandomIntakeOffset` to see the difference?

Comment: I actually tried setting both to large numbers (60000) and didn't see any delays. However, may I ask how you set the properties as that very well may be my problem. I set them up in a setup thread in a BeanShell sampler. `props.put("GetRandomIntakeOffset", 60000 * props.get("RandDelayMod"));` , where `RandDelayMod` is set to either 1 or 0 depending on if I want or don't want delays. Note again, that when I print the value of `GetRandomIntakeOffset` I see the value is indeed 60000

Comment: I tried your scenario (setup thread with Beanshell sampler, which was setting `props.put("GetRandomIntakeOffset", 1000 * props.get("someOtherInt"));`, main thread using it in Uniform Random Timer as `${__P(GetRandomIntakeOffset)}`) and it still works. But I am using JMeter 3, could it be some older version's bug?

Comment: Thanks Kiril. It seems that Jmeter was experiencing other issues and I have since gotten this working.